# Создание GUI таблицы заполняемой через буфер обмена на Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, буферизация

Как я могу реализовать таблицу такого вида:

### [image: Table for gui]

Заголовок, названия и количество столбцов всегда одинаковы. Количество строк должно варьировать в зависимости от длины таблицы, вставляемой пользователем через буфер обмена.  Кнопка `Paste` соответственно, должна вставлять тот фрагмент таблицы, который был скопирован пользователем.

Comment: Покажите пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: У меня нет никакого примера, как раз сейчас пытаюсь его сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать статический метод QApplication.clipboard():

```
def ...:
    self.buttonPaste.clicked.connect(self.paste)

# метод для чтения данных из буфера обмена
def paste(self):
    text = QApplication.clipboard().text()
    print(text)
    if not text: # если text не пустой
        # Далее делим полученные данные на строки (столбцы)
        # при помощи соответствующих разделителей
        # и заполняем таблицу
```